# Use multiple filters in Scapy's "sniff" function

Tags: python, spyder, scapy, sniffing

A friend and I are currently making a sniffing application in Python using the Scapy library. We have a GUI interface where we can choose filters and protocols. We want to sniff the network using one or more filters but don't know how to do. For now we tried the following code :

```
capture=scapy.sniff(filter="tcp and udp",timeout=5)
print(capture)
```

It works well but it sniffs using only the first filter (tcp filter in this case). We also tried with the following code but same :

```
capture1=scapy.sniff(filter="tcp",timeout=5)
capture2=scapy.sniff(filter="udp",timeout=5)
print(capture1)
print(capture2)
```

So, is it possible to sniff using more than one filter and if so, do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are telling Scapy to sniff packets that are both TCP and UDP.

When I try this (Linux, current Scapy development version), I get a warning message `tcpdump: expression rejects all packets` and the filter is not applied.

You probably want to use a `or` instead of `and`: `capture=scapy.sniff(filter="tcp or udp",timeout=5)`.